# Facebook like dialog position

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-like, position

Im using the Facebook like and send: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Iis it possible to get the like dialog that pops up to go north, and dont south?
Like illustrated here: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg201/scaled.php?server=201&filename=fblike.jpg&res=landing

I know its possible with the send dialog, but cant get it to work with the like dialog.

Comment: No, not yet. Dont think its possible